# C# reverse proxy via websocket / SignalR

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr, blazor, reverse-proxy

I have one public facing ASPNETCORE server. Then I have multiple small blazor-server applications running on multiple machines in customers infrastructure (behind firewall etc). It must be possible, but how difficult or easy would it be to setup a reverse proxy over websockets/signlar so I can reach the sites from public facing server?

Browser (domain.com/theSite)->Public server (WebSocket/SignalR-server-Hub) | Client(WebSocket/SignalR) -> 192.168.1.100 (blazor server app)

This article describes the concept:
https://dev.to/hgsgtk/reverse-http-proxy-over-websocket-in-go-part-1-13n4

Comment: That one reverse proxy needs to handle lots of concurrent connections for all applications . That means it needs a bunch of memory and is a single point of failure (if it goes down all of the connections for all apps will be disconnected). With that in consideration, it should be "easy" (just find a doc about reverse proxying websockets).